# Can't access domain shared folder by name but I can by IP

Tags: dns, dhcp, domain, shared-folders

I have computer with windows server 2008 r2 and a router works as dhcp server. I created a domain on the server and I created users.

I made the clients access the network via new users of domain then the computers work fine but after sometime some of them cant access folder of domain server except by using it's IP. Sometime when I change the IP of the client then it's working fine but after a while the problem comes again.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ahgh
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : fws.com
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : fws.com
                                            wr

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : wr
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connection

Comment: Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-19-DB-83-E5-12
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.67
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.66
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.66
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.66
                                            8.8.8.8

Comment: 192.168.1.66 is the router ip

Comment: the router dns config as follow:

Comment: router#dns-server 192.168.1.66 8.8.8.8

Comment: What is nslookup telling about your host and ip?

Comment: helppppppppppppppp!

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add information to your post. The comment are neither designed nor suited for this.